# Yii2 sluggable behavior in migration

Tags: yii2, migration, behavior, slug

I want to add new column `slug` to existing table. Here is my migration code:

```
$this->addColumn('region', 'slug', $this->string()->unique());
```

Also I want to avoid `NULL`'s in existing records. For that purpose I have created behavior:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        ...
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title_ru',
            'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
            'ensureUnique' => true,
            'immutable' => true,
            'skipOnEmpty' => false,
        ],
        ...
    ];
}
```

And rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        [['slug'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
        [['slug'], 'unique'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

So I thought that if I call `save()` method, `slug` will be automatically generated in existing record. Here is my simple code in the same migration:

```
$regions = Region::find()->all();
foreach ($regions as $region) {
    $region->save();
}
```

But it does not work as expecting:

```
+----+------------------------+------------------------+------+
| id | title_ru               | title_uk               | slug |
+----+------------------------+------------------------+------+
|  1 | Интернет               | Інтернет               |      |
|  2 | Интернет+ТВ            | Інтернет+ТБ            | -2   |
|  3 | Корпоративным клиентам | Корпоративним кліентам | -3   |
+----+------------------------+------------------------+------+
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks for any advice.

Even more strange is that everything works perfect in admins CRUD.

---

**UPDATE #1**

Tried to use `validate()` method, but still no results.

```
$regions = Region::find()->all();
foreach ($regions as $region) {
    if ($region->validate()) {
        $region->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `intl` PHP extension enabled?

Comment: @rob006 seems like yes, but it does not have `default_locale`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything is good with behavior. The problem is in Cyrillic symbols and php configuration.